# How to modify the following code to ignore rows with 0 and shows the output weekly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

My following query gives me the output shown in figure 1. I want to change it so that it gives the output in figure 2. I want to show the weekwise (even if the value is 0) Here is the query. Please help.

```
SELECT @MaxDate = @MaxDate
    ,@MinDate = dateadd(week, (@LastXWeeks + 1), @MaxDate);

WITH AllDates
AS (
    SELECT @MinDate AS xDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Dateadd(day, 1, xDate)
    FROM AllDates AS ad
    WHERE ad.xDate < @MaxDate
    )
SELECT 'playing' AS activity
    ,ad.xDate
    ,Isnull(t.TimePerDay, 0) AS TimePerDay
FROM AllDates AS ad WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN @test AS t ON ad.xDate = t.DATE
```

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: can we put here `WHERE TimePerDay != 0`

Comment: No because it is showing the sum of playing and 0 if no game played. I will update the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want results per week, so group by week:

```
WITH AllDates
AS (
    SELECT @MinDate AS xDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Dateadd(day, 1, xDate)
    FROM AllDates AS ad
    WHERE ad.xDate < @MaxDate
    )
SELECT 
  'playing' AS activity
  ,min(ad.xDate) -- or max or the week number, whichever you like best
  ,Isnull(sum(t.TimePerDay), 0) AS TimePerDay
FROM AllDates AS ad WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN @test AS t ON ad.xDate = t.DATE
GROUP BY datepart(wk, ad.xDate);
```

Comment: I changed the last line to group by datepart(wk, ad.xDate),Isnull(t.TimePerDay, 0) because it was giving error but the output is different

Comment: What error did you get? I suppose you forgot to replace `t.TimePerDay` with `sum(t.TimePerDay)`?

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spGetWalkingTimeOftheUsersPerWeek_updated_6_August, Line 88
Column '@test.TimePerDay' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Yes that's it. You tried to access `t.TimePerDay`, but there are seven of them per week, so you must aggregate them: `SUM(t.TimePerDay)`.

Comment: It is making sense. Let me verify the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by or week no in comment? I am newbie

Comment: Each week of the year has a number. `datepart(wk, ad.xDate)` is this week number. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174420%28v=SQL.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT @MaxDate = @MaxDate
    ,@MinDate = dateadd(week, (@LastXWeeks + 1), @MaxDate);

WITH AllDates
AS (
    SELECT @MinDate AS xDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Dateadd(day, 1, xDate)
    FROM AllDates AS ad
    WHERE ad.xDate < @MaxDate
    )
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 'playing' AS activity
    ,ad.xDate
    ,Isnull(t.TimePerDay, 0) AS TimePerDay
FROM AllDates AS ad WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN @test AS t ON ad.xDate = t.DATE
) as t WHERE TimePerDay<>0
```

Comment: Please check my question update. Actually I wana show week wise, even if the value is 0. I guess your solution will truncate 0